# QTableWidget, centrar texto y cambiar color a un VerticalHeader en especifico

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, pyqt

Estoy realizando una tabla con `QTableWidgetItem`,
el problema que se me presenta esta en el `VertialHeader`

Necesito que el texto este centrado y que definir un color diferente de texto a algunos items; por ejemplo el item (`Gastos` debe de ser rojo).

Dentro del `stylesheet` intente los siguiente para modificar la alineación del texto pero no funciono:

```
QHeaderView::section:vertical{ qproperty-defaultAlignment: AlignHCenter; }
```

en cuanto al color del texto del `itemVerticalHeader`, no he podido resolver nada.

espero puedan ayudarme dejo una captura de pantalla de la tabla:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primero, para especificar la alineación del texto vía hoja de estilos si quieres ambos headers con el texto centrado puedes hacer:

```
QHeaderView{qproperty-defaultAlignment: AlignHCenter}
```

Otra opción es hacerlo vía código:

```
tableWidget.verticalHeader().setDefaultAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignHCenter)
```

Ahora bien, dado que estás usando Qt Designer para crear la estructura de tu tabla, puedes especificar individualmente si quieres tanto la alineación como el color de los items del header modificando sus propiedades en diálogo de edición de la tabla:

1. Click derecho en la tabla y click en la opción <kbd>Edit Items...</kbd> del menú:

   [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
2. Seleccionas la pestaña <kbd>Rows</kbd>, el item que quieres modificar y click en el botón <kbd>Properties <<</kbd>

   [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
3. Busca la propiedad `textAlignment` y en el valor asigna `AlignHCenter`.

   [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
4. Con esto centramos ese item. Ahora, para el color del texto busca la propiedad  `foreground` y en `Style`  asigna solid como valor.

   [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
5. Por último ve a `Color` justo debajo y selecciona el color que quieras.

   [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Con esto puedes conseguir lo que quieres:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: tuve un error de escritura estoy utilizando pyqt y qtdesigner que incluye pyqt-tools

Comment: Revsky01 la respuesta es para qtdesigner (que tenga fondo oscuro o cambien los iconos es por el tema de mi escritorio solamente), que lo instales vía pyqt-tools, vía binarios o por paquetes del sistema es indiferente en este aspecto. ¿Dónde está exactamente el problema?¿No encuentras alguna opción?¿Algún error?¿Dónde ocurre y cúando?